# How to do a webrequest with JSON Body containing arrays or lists?

Tags: powershell

### The Situation

I need to interact with a REST API which requires JSON post data.
So I started working with something like this:

### Simple working example

```
$ReqURI = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $ReqURI -Body @{
    'api.token' = "api.token"
    'action' = 'create item'
} -Verbose| fl *
```

So I tested it with httpbin.org:

[image: Working]

### Issue

But If you need to use a list or array in the body part like this example:

```
$ReqURI = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $ReqURI -Body @{
    'api.token' = "api.token"
    'names' = @('rJENK', 'rFOOBAR')
} -Verbose| fl *
$Response
```

... you get something like a converting error:

[image: Converting Issue]

So I thought I could convert the body myself into a JSON string and using the `-Depth` parameter from `ConvertTo-JSON`. In addition to that I tried how it looks like if I convert the hashtable into an object first.

But both tries return the same and even worse result:

[image: not working]

So finally I switched to `Invoke-WebRequest`. But the results here are the same.

My reference is a working api call with the JSON string:

```
"api.token" : "fooobar",
"names": [
    "rJENK",
    "rFOOBAR"
  ]
```

#### Personal Solution

I figured out a workaround. It seems like the api I'm working with can't handle requests containing nested elements or array created by PowerShell.

Non working example:

```
$ReqURI = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $ReqURI -Body @{
    'api.token' = "api.token"
    'names' = @('rJENK', 'rFOOBAR')
} -Verbose| fl *
$Response
```

Instead I had to fake an array with indexes. That's the workaround:

```
$ReqURI = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $ReqURI -Body @{
    'api.token' = "api.token"
    'names[0]' = 'rJENK'
    'names[1]' = 'rFOOBAR'
} -Verbose| fl *
$Response
```

Answer (score 11):

So now you have to use the *content type* as *Application/Json* like:

```
$ReqURI = 'http://httpbin.org/post'

$Jsonbody= @{
    'api.token' = "api.token"
    'names' = @('rJENK', 'rFOOBAR')
        } | ConvertTo-Json

$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Uri $ReqURI -Body $body -Verbose| fl *
```

This should do your work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the webserver can't handle requests with this content type.

Comment: @OCram85: We have to think then. I think that is the main reason why it is not accepting the Json type. any thought on XML conversion ?